# Spork timer not resetting between runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spork

This is a copy+paste of an [issue](https://github.com/timcharper/spork/issues/151) I created on github, but I'm asking here too in case someone knows how to fix it

---

Using spork 0.9.0.rc9, I've noticed that the timer which displays how long specs are taking to run is not resetting itself between runs and is instead outputting the total time that has accumulated since the spork server was started.

Steps to reproduce:

1. start spork from console with command spork
2. in another window run rspec . --drb
3. observe that specs take X seconds to run and that console output verifies this
4. wait 60 seconds, modify a controller spec, and repeat step 2
5. observe that specs take about Y seconds to run, but console output claims that they took (X + Y + 60) seconds.
6. wait 10 minutes, repeat step 2
7. observe that specs run in Z seconds but console output puts the figure at (X + Y + Z + 600) seconds

My spec_helper is just the standard one that rspec-rails generates for you and I've put everything inside the spork prefork block as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|  
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end
```

Am I doing it wrong? Or is spork borked?

Answer (score 4):

There is a temporary fix for this, it is a known rspec issue.

The temporary fix, which may not work with future versions of rspec, is as follows:

```
Spork.each_run do
  # you are advised that this may break in future versions of rspec
  $rspec_start_time = Time.now  
end
```

**UPDATE:**
it was reported in guard-rspec [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/61) and in rspec-core [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/475).